# WPF itemscontrol binding to collection of controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

I'm trying to bind to a collection of controls I generate dynamically:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CustomFields}">
```

And the code:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Control> CustomFields
    {
        get
        {
            return GetCustomFields();
        }
    }
```

The Getcustomfields just generates some controls like a ComboBox, textbox etc. The binding seems to work, but the window doesn't show any of my controls. Probably because I need an datatemplate in the itemscontrol. My question is what kind of datatemplate do I need?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following property like with the same XAML as you use:

```
public ObservableCollection<UIElement> Controls
{
    get
    {
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<UIElement>();
        collection.Add(new Button { Content = "Hello world" });

        return collection;
    }
}
```

Maybe your problem comes from somewhere else... Can you give us the code needed to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Thanks, the changing the ObservableCollection to the UIElement type instead of control works. I cannot vote yet sorry.